# Include a version control tag in VSS

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I was reading Code Complete 2 and it mentions this:

> Many version-control tools wil insert version information into a file. In CVS, for exmple the characters

```
// $id$
```

> Will Automaticly expand to

```
// $id: ClassName.java, v 1.1 2004/02/05 00:36:42 ismene Exp $
```

So now I would like to do something similar with VSS for our SQL scripts

I have been googling around for the answer but can't find it. Is this possible? can someone maybe point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it myself @ 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d826hy97(VS.80).aspx